# Efficiently storing and loading data on demand (perhaps similar to video game assets)

Tags: c#, wpf, storage, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am looking for a good way of storing and loading lots of data in a WPF application. I am currently looking at protobuf-net, but there might be better ways.

**Context**
As a fun little project, I am writing a program that will help me organize everything for my D&D (Dungeons and Dragons) campaign, which includes having all the source material available and editable per my desired rule-changes.

I am currently working on the part of the program that display all spells in the game, and allows for them to be edited and for new spells to be added. There are over 400 spells in D&D, not counting any spells I might add myself. Each spell is similar in size to [this](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/dream). Each spell (or other object in D&D) will be represented by its own class in code, to allow for fancy stuff like searching, ordering, and simulations. In addition to spells there are many other objects that will be stored and many of these items will be dependant on each other. Each spell for example has a DnDItems field that contains the items required to cast it, where a DnDItem is just another D&D specific class that will be stored seperately.

**The Problem**
With this much data that is represented as more than just a string, what is the best way to store and load this? I use a WPF ListView to view the list of spells, and the selected spell will show detailed information in a panel to the side. In addition to this, the spells will be linked to from many other places from the program, as many things in D&D are interconnected. I am considering protobuf-net since I've heard many great things about it. 
The most important part for me is performance, so what would be the best solution?

Edit: The program and all data it uses is currently only planned to be available locally.

Comment: If the spells are all stored in a text file...Then i guess you are already using the most efficient way :) ... Unless u share ur codes with us :) ....

Comment: Gee if only there was a _base_ where you could store this _data_?

Comment: _Each spell (or other object in D&D) will be represented by its own class in code_  You're going to write over 400 spell classes?  Good luck.

Comment: I assume he means instances of a spell class and maybe he's a hobbyist rather than a professional developer.

Comment: @juharr sorry, meant to say *A* spell, as every other gameobject is going to be a class

Comment: @MickyD why *wouldn't you*, more like :) I may be biased, of course. But if "human readable/editable without tools" isn't an important feature, size and speed can still be important considerations, even for a local-only file. It depends on the size and use-case, obviously.

Comment: @MarcGravell true, I’m not a fan of text-based serialisation.  I miss the days of IPersistStream

Answer (score 0):

A database is kind of obvious to those of use who focus on enterprise level software.
For an app which will work on a desktop where each user just wants their own data store it's not always the best option though.

I recommend you look into serialisation and deserialization. This is very fast - significantly faster than storing in a local database.
You just build your classes with public properties and you can serialise them.
Here's some code from my game.

```
public static void SaveScenario(string fileURL, Scenario scenario)
{
    scenario.ScenarioFile = fileURL;
    using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileURL, FileMode.Create))
    {
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Scenario));
        ser.WriteObject(writer, scenario);
    } 
}
public static Scenario ReadScenario(string fileURL)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileURL, FileMode.Open);
    XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Scenario));
    Scenario deserializedScenario = (Scenario)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
    reader.Close();
    fs.Close();
    return deserializedScenario;
}
```

That reads and writes to an xml file.
Scenario is just a public class with public properties:

```
public class Scenario
{

    public string ScenarioName { get; set; } = "";
    public string ScenarioDescription { get; set; } = "";
    public string ScenarioFile { get; set; } = "";
    public int NumTurns { get; set; } = 0;
```

....

```
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool[,] ValidTerrain = new bool[,]
```

The IgnoreDataMember attribute avoids serialising a property.
Some of the properties are collections of complex objects.

Once you read your file into memory then you can use linq to objects to search, sort or whatever.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects

You could also combine this with zipping the file if you wanted to keep the size down or store several files.
400 spells is not very much data.

I don't know how much overlap there is of components but let's imagine something like a component is used numerous times. You could have a components collection property in your spell class and you don't want to repeat eye-of-newt many times. You could handle that by using an ID. So you store a list of components and each has an int id.  The list of components on a spell could then just have ComponentId and use that as a foreign key in a join to components.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I was considering XML before but it seemed slow and protobuf seems to be a faster version of serialization, the only downside is that the serialized files are less (or not at all) readable. Good to know that serialization is the route to take though

Comment: Protobuf would be way over-engineering things and deserialization of even pretty large files is lightning fast. Assuming the file is on the user's machine, if you were dragging this over a network then that's a different story.

Comment: You can persist protobuf to disk and there are comparisons demonstrating protobuf is a bit faster than json. For single user and data on the c:\ drive it's a few percent better than something doesn't need any improving.